# is it possible to put multiple instances of ec2 under one domain?

Tags: domain, amazon-ec2

Is it possible to have multiple instances of aws under a single domain ?
I am trying to host data in several instances, and there'll be one server, but if I want to give my client side script to contact data sources directly without my central server, then it'll be cross domain, which I want to avoid for several reasons. 
Possible ? Solutions ? Advices ?

Comment: No answers yet ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are asking for can't really be done without using cross-domain calls.

Possible solutions I have seen.

Host static content through Amazon S3 (look at the html for twitter sometime) and just make an explicit load from another location.

For dynamic content, you really will need one location returning the data (avoiding this is what a hacker would try to do to abuse your sites good name and return malicious content).  For example, you can have the domain do a CNAME lookup to an amazon load balancer, which routes traffic to several apache instances.  These in turn talk to several app servers (for example using mod_jk with java) which talk to the database, and all of this data is returned up the chain to the web server which returns it to the client.

Can you try to describe in a bit more detail what you are trying to do?  I don't quite get why you can't just have a central server handle the requests and return the data itself.

Comment: There's going to be a lot of data, which I am planning to host on ec2 instances. So wanted a way for browsers to communicate with data directly.. 

I think this is achievable using iFrames.. will give it a try..